# What are the three top Blogs for WPF?

Tags: .net, wpf, mvvm

I have several bookmarked, but only have so much time in a day to read/study blogs.  If I were to pick three blogs to read on a daily basis for deep understanding of WPF what should I read?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't know about reading everyday, but these have helped immensely:

- http://blogs.msdn.com/mikehillberg/default.aspx
- http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/
- http://karlshifflett.wordpress.com/
- http://www.drwpf.com/blog/

ok -- so that's 4.  Bea Stollnitz doesn't seem to get updated as much anymore, but it's good.  Jaime Rodriguez rounds out my list.

Comment: Bea has created an archive of her blogs here: https://github.com/bstollnitz/old-wpf-blog

Answer (score 3):

Josh Smith's blog :
http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/

Answer (score 2):

Marlon Grech's Blog: http://marlongrech.wordpress.com/

Answer (score 1):

http://blogs.msdn.com/jgoldb/default.aspx

http://karlshifflett.wordpress.com/

no particular order.

Answer (score 1):

Touch choice, 3 is far to few :)
I use the blog list that jaime rodriguez put together.
http://blogs.msdn.com/jaimer/pages/wpf-bloggers.aspx

Like previous posters, I agree that Josh smiths posts are good for the coding-part WPF, but I also like the expression Blend team blog(kirupa and pete blois individual blogs are also excellent) and Robby Ingbretsens blog (been a little bit unactive since mix).

whoops. more than 3 :)